# Condition to check if second class is open or closed using jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="menu-wrap closed" style="max-height: 1px;">
</div>

<div class="menu-wrap open" style="max-height: 1000px;">
</div>
```

On button click I need to check whether the divs are  having class as open or closed Condition to check if second class is open or closed in jquery/js

Comment: Do you want to check it exactly with position of the class?

Comment: on button click I need to check whether it is having class as open or closed

Comment: then just use `.hasClass(classname)`

Comment: Please select an answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#myelement').hasClass('open')`

`$('#myelement').hasClass('closed')`

The `#myelement` part is the ID of the element, it can be replaced with any other selector though

```
if ($('#myelement').hasClass('open'))
    // element is open
else if ($('#myelement').hasClass('closed'))
    // element is closed
```

or simpler

```
if ($('#myelement').hasClass('open'))
    // element is open
else
    // element is not open
```

Comment: do I have to use condition if along with this ? like  if($('.menu-wrap').hasClass('open'))

Comment: hasClass() method return boolean value.. do what ever you want with that

Comment: Just added some examples of how to use it, as Pavan said already, it is either `true` or `false`

Comment: true or false or 0 or 1

Comment: In javascript 0 is treated as false, 1 is treated as true so you can compare the result against 0 or 1, true or false. It doesn't really matter

`$('#custom-header').hasClass('open') == 1` is the same as `$('#custom-header').hasClass('open') == true`

`$('#custom-header').hasClass('open') == 0` is the same as `$('#custom-header').hasClass('open') == false`

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the class has been applied,

```
 if($('#selector').hasClass('closed')){
      // your code here if the element has class named closed
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> "On button click I need to check whether the divs are having class as open or closed"

Sure:

```
$(button).click(function(){
   if($(".menu-wrap").hasClass("open")){
     // open button logic here
   }else{
     // close button logic here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using jQuery[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to check it.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/0rwxph46/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.menu-wrap').hasClass('open')) {
        // Your code
    } else {
        // Your code
    }
});
```